# Cisco Switch Temperature monitoring problem

Tags: monitoring, cisco

we are looking for monitoring Cisco Catalyst 2960 temperature, fan, voltage via Orion Universal device poller. we added "ciscoEnvMonFanState" but didnt show any Fan speed value or temperature value.

when we browse web admin console of the cisco switches, it`s only shows the temperature and fan value is OK. but we need to monitoring the specific value each time. what should I do? 
how can I find these value and add to orion solarwinds monitoring gauge?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that ciscoEnvMonFanState only provides 6 levels :

1 : normal

2 : warning

3 : critical

4 : shutdown

5 : notPresent

6 : notFunctioning

So it's basically the same as "sh env" on the switch. It only tells you if temp is OK or not.

Maybe you can use the [Cisco SNMP Object Navigator](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do) to see if there is another oid/mib that would suit your needs.

Comment: can you offer other OID for Catalyst 2960? we find our switch OID with snmpwalk, OID: iso.3.6.1.4.1.9.1.694, but there is not any value for temperature? very ambiguous!

Comment: try ciscoEnvMonTemperatureStatusValue (1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.13.1.3.1.3). I don't know if it's present on the 2960, but worth trying.